# how to use attribute name including colon in jsx

Tags: reactjs, attributes

I want to use attribute name including colon(:) in JSX.

ex)

```
<div sa:name='timer'></div>
```

I know react can't use a colon in the attribute name.

how is it possible to use that attribute name?

please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

you an try this

```
const props = {} 
props ["sa:name"] = "timer";
<div props={props}></div>
```

now you can access props["sa:name"] in your children component.

Comment: Can be shortened to `<div prop1='prop1' {...{ 'sa:name': 'timer' }}></div>`